# Can you create Draft collections for individual sites NOT searchable by everyone

Tags: document-library, document, wiki-pages

My people save their drafts into the main library and its a mess.  In SP2016 I would like the departments to share their own creations (WIKI style) in a DRAFTS space but have to DELIBERATELY CHOOSE to save results into the library.  I could really use something clean but plainly noted that they are saving to a searchable library.

Is this a situation that has to be developed or is there something out of the box that can help us?